# Python: For loop list gives IndexError

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]

for i in a:
   print(a[i])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't undertand why I get this error.

Comment: `for i in a:` is iterating over the elements of `a` not the indexes. Thus, you are using the elements themselves as indexes into the list.

Comment: @JohanL How can I iterate over the indexes?

Comment: `for i, e in enumerate(a):` will give both the index and the value.

Comment: @davedwards As long as the element is not repeating.

Comment: @JohanL so i is the index, and e, each value in the list? Am I right?

Comment: But are you sure you *want* the index and not the element itself? Often the element is what you really want, if you think about it.

Comment: Yes, that is true, `i` is the index and `e` is the element (or value).

Comment: @JohanL Awesome thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the index of an element, it is possible to `enumerate` the data in the array, using

```
for i, e in enumerate(a):
    print(a[i]) # assuming this is just a placeholder for a more complex instruction
```

gives what you want, where `i` is the index and `e`is the (value of) the element in the list. But often you do not need the index since you want to use the value of the element directly. In those cases it is better to do just

```
for e in a:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 4):

You are referencing the value not the index. 
Try:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i])
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need an index in the example you give, since you are only printing the values of the items in the list, in which case printing the items directly would suffice:

```
for i in a:
    print(i)
```