# unexpected result with code summing sequence

Tags: python

I want to write code that returns a new list where the i<sup>th</sup> element is the sum of the first i + 1 elements of the original list. For example, for the list `[1, 2, 3]`, the result is `[1, 3, 6]`.

So I've written this:

```
def cumulative_sum(numbers: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    """Returns the cumulative sum of the given list of numbers."""
    cum_sum = []
    for t in numbers:
        cum_sum.append(sum(numbers[:t]))
    return cum_sum


print(cumulative_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
```

However, when I run this I get `[1, 18, 9, 13, 18, 24, 31, 39, 48, 58]`, where there is an inexplicable 18 and the sequence seems to only work after the first 3 values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: For loop list gives IndexError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737413/python-for-loop-list-gives-indexerror)

Comment: I think it's time to learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `t` ranges over the *elements* of `numbers`
, not their indices – you're summing the `numbers[i]` first numbers instead of the `i`
 first numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing indexes and elements when iterating

You can do something like this:

```
def cumulative_sum(numbers: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    """Returns the cumulative sum of the given list of numbers."""
    #initialize with the first element
    cum_sum = [numbers[0]]

    # start iterating with the second element
    for i in range(1, len(numbers)):
        # add the current element to the previous cumsum
        cum_sum.append(cum_sum[-1] + numbers[i])
    return cum_sum


print(cumulative_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
```

Comment: where "something like this" means "I have not run this code"?

Comment: Somehing like this means there are other approaches to solve the problem, like initializing cum_sum to an empty list and dealing with the case where cum_sum is empty

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki thank you very much, this answer clears up my confusion

Answer (score 0):

It often makes sense to implement such functions as generator,

```
def cumulative_sum(numbers):
    """Returns the cumulative sum of the given list of numbers."""
    total = 0
    for t in numbers:
        total += t
        yield total
```

so you can loop over the result lazily `for i in cumulative_sum([1, 2, 3]):` or turn it into a list by `list(cumulative_sum([1, 2, 3]))` if you really need to. This function, however, is exactly the same as `itertools.accumulate` so you might as well use that:

```py
from itertools import accumulate 

# [1, 3, 6]
print(list(accumulate([1, 2, 3])))
```